# R DT Flexible Table Width

Tags: r, dt

I would like to make a datatable using DT that does not change width when the browser window changes. The example below almost does what I am trying to do, all of the column widths are locked except the first column, which is still flexible. I would like all of the columns to be locked without specifying widths in pixels for each column.

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

datatable(mtcars,
          options = list(
                autowidth = TRUE
           )) %>%
  formatStyle(columns = 1:ncol(mtcars),
      `width` = "100%")
```

Comment: Do you want to embed this in a website? In this case, you could wrap the `datatable` in an `HTML` container with fixed width to archieve that.

Comment: I would like to use the output in a .Rmd file. I am already using the container argument so that this table inherits a multi-level header from a different table. As a result I am really hoping to find a solution that does not involve the container argument.

Answer (score 0):

The following `Rmd` document gives a fixed width of 100 pixels to the datatable

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
shiny::div(
  width = "100px",
  DT::datatable(mtcars))
```
````

The usage in shiny is similar

```
shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = shiny::div(
    width = "100px",
    DT::datatable(mtcars)), 
  server = function(...){}
)
```

Comment: I don't believe that the first chunk functions as described, the table still fills the entire width of the page and does not change if I set it to 1px instead of 100px. Additionally, I don't want to specify a fixed number of pixels, I would like the table to size itself but not expand across the entire page.